# T-SQL Function with an sql_variant input in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, function, linq, t-sql

I followed this guide to use a user defined function in a linq to entities query.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/how-to-call-custom-database-functions

I'm using Entity Framework 6.2 with model-first approach.

The implementation appears to be working but I'm having an issue with one of my input parameters not showing up when updating my edmx model. My function has two input parameters, the first one is type sql_variant, the second one is type varchar, but only the one varchar parameter shows up in the model, while in the SQL definition it still has both input parameters.

And the error I get is either of a missing parameter if I only pass that one varchar input, or that there's no overload for that function since on the edmx side it only accepts one input parameter.

Is it possible for EF to recognize my sql_variant input parameter correctly?

Thanks.